# Origem da pronúncia de algumas consoantes mudas

Tags: ortografia, diferenças-transatlânticas, pronúncia

Em Portugal, correntemente, algumas palavras que possuem consoante muda têm a pronúncia diferente daquela usada no Brasil.

Algumas palavras comuns podem servir de exemplo: **recepção** e **confecção**. No Brasil, o `p` e o `c`, respectivamente, são pronunciados.

Alguma vez, em Portugal, essas consoantes já foram ditas? Se não, a partir de quando, no Brasil, tal pronúncia surgiu?

Comment: Apenas por curiosidade, pois não ficou claro pra mim. Em Portugal, essas palavras são pronunciadas sem as consoantes mudas? Algo como "receção"?

Comment: @James, sim, exactamente assim: "rec**é**ção". O `p`, em `ep`, é um indicador de que se precisa acentuar a vogal antecedente.

Comment: No local onde vivo(Guimarães) algumas pessoas dizem recepção(dizem o p) outras dizem receção(não leiem o p)

Comment: Mas com o novo acordo ortográfico as palavras em que existem consoantes mudas, passam a ser escritas sem essa mesma consoante

Comment: @InêsBarataFeioBorges Obrigado pelo comentário! Sabe se em mais partes de Portugal se falam essas consoantes? Pelo menos em Lisboa e no Alentejo, nunca as ouvi.

Comment: Havia no português resmas de palavras com consoantes mudas, como *assumpto, escriptor* e *auctor*. Havia algumas que eram mudas no Brasil e não em Portugal, e vice-versa. O Brasil eliminou oficialmente as suas consoantes mudas em 1943, Portugal eliminou as suas em 1911, exceto as precedidas de vogal aberta, como em *espectáculo* (há muito tempo pronunciado *espetáculo*). Estas foram agora eliminadas com o acordo ortográfico de 1990. Quando é que consoantes deixaram de ser ou passaram a ser pronunciadas em cada país, não sei dizer, mas imagino que varie de palavra para palavra.

Comment: São consoantes etimologicas, orrespondem a consoantes que foram pronunciadas em tempos.

Comment: Atenção que as consoantes mudas não têm qualquer papel de abrir vogais, simplesmente esse foi um critério, entre outros, para manter consoantes mudas na escrita. Há vogais abertas sem consoante: translação, inflação, etc, e vogais fechadas com consoante: actriz, actualidade, etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://emportuguezgrande.blogspot.com/p/a-origem-das-consoantes-mudas.html

A Origem das "Consoantes Mudas Diacríticas"

A Reforma Ortográfica unilateral portuguesa de 1911 (RO1911) introduziu na ortografia particularidades diacríticas de complexidade inédita em séculos de evolução ortográfica do Português.

A mais aberrante das inovações da diacrítica de 1911 consistiu na manutenção na ortografia, por motivos supostamente fonéticos, de algumas consoantes mudas etimológicas que tinham começado a ser introduzidas artificialmente na ortografia no século 16.

O conteúdo da RO1911 que estabelece a permanência na ortografia de consoantes mudas por suposta relevância fonética, é o que decorre da conjugação das 3 bases seguintes:
Base VII. Nenhuma consoante se duplicará no interior de um vocábulo, senão quando a pronunciação assim o exija, o que só acontece com rr, ss, mm, nn, como mas seguintes palavras; carro, emmular, ennegrecer. Nesta conformidade, escrever-se hão com letras singelas as seguintes palavras, e outras que é hábito escrever com letras dobradas: abade [abbade], acusar [accusar], adição [addição], afecto [affecto], sugerir [suggerir], agravo [aggravo], êle [elle], ela [ella], aludir [alludir], chama [chamma], pano [panno], anexo [annexo], aparecer [apparecer], atribuir [attribuir], meter [metter], atitude [attitude], etc. […]
Base VIII. São suprimidas as consoantes mudas, quando não influam no valor das vogais que as precedem; ex.: autor [auctor], restrito [restricto], produto [producto], produção [producção], pronto [prompto], presunção [presumpção], satisfação [satisfacção], praticar [practicar], tratar [tractar], retratar [retractar], sinal [signal], Madalena [Magdalena], aumento [augmento], Inácio [Ignacio], Inês [Ignez], assunto [assumpto], assinar [assignar], sono [somno], dano [damno], condenar [condemnar], etc.
Base IX. São conservadas as consoantes, usualmente mudas, quando facultativamente se profiram, ou quando influam no valor da vogal que as precede; ex: contracção, reacção, direcção, excepção, espectáculo, carácter, rectidão. […]

Sintetizando, a Base 7 e parte da Base 8 determinaram a eliminação de todas as consoantes mudas, e a Base 9 e parte da Base 8 excluíram daquela eliminação a pequena parte dessas consoantes mudas que seguia uma vogal com abertura excecional.

Para entender melhor o âmbito e o efeito da aplicação das bases 7, 8 e 9 da RO1911, considere-se o seguinte conjunto de palavras grafadas segundo a ortografia predominante antes de 1911.

Legenda:
- a vermelho, consoantes mudas
- a negro, palavras em que foram eliminadas todas as consoantes mudas;
- a verde, palavras que mantiveram uma consoante muda;
- a azul, palavras que tinham (e têm) vogais átonas abertas sem consoante muda que "assinale a pronúncia correta".

Abbadia, acceitar, accender, accentuar, accidente, acclamar, accommetter, accommodar, accordar, accrescentar, accudir, accumular, accusar, actuar, actualizar, addição, affecto, affigurar, afflirmar, affligir, afflorar, Affonso, affrontar, affim, aggravar, aggredir, allado, Allemanha, alli, alliviar, alludir, alluvião, amarello, annel, anno, annuir, annunciar, apparecer, apparelho, appellar, appetite, applicar, appoiar, approvar, approximar, aquecer, aquelle, arrefecer arruella attingir atrellado atropello attender attentar attenuar atterar attestar attinente atttitude attrahir attribulado attribuir attrito commodo collar collete bacello bagatella baixella ballão béllico belliscão bello Benguella bocca Bruxellas cabello canella capella castello caveira clientella colação collaborar collectivo collégio collina collocar cautella cavallo collosso commandar commentar commetter commigo commissão commover commodo commum communhão contracto corar cutello delação desannuviar dilação dilecto directo ebolição effectivo efficácia efficiência electricidade elle emballar emmoldurar emmudecer entallar especular esquecer estrella exacto exaggero excellente facção fallar fallecer freguesia gamella gramma gotta honesto illação inflação installar intelligência invasão janell laccar mallogro Marianno Mello metter molle obrigar occidente occasionar occorrer occultar occupar offensa oceano offegar offender offerecer official offuscar olfacto oligarquia oliveira ominoso onerar opaco opinião oppor opportuno opprimir oriente orthographia ovelha panella pelle pello penna perenne preoccupar prometter rebellião recepção recomnendar relator relles repellir republica rhetórica padeiro sábbado satisfacção secco sentinella soccorro soffrer sollicitar supletivo,tecto tractar tyranno vadio valle vassallo vedor vella velludo vexar.

Como bem se percebe, até 1911 os leitores pronunciavam vogais com abertura excecional sem recorrer à presença de uma consoante muda para determinar a pronúncia correta da palavra grafada, dado que a generalidade das consoantes mudas seguia uma vogal átona fechada ou seguia uma vogal tónica sem particularidade fonética excecional.

No entanto, a RO1911 tentou artificiosamente construir uma realidade nova; assim:
- em "commetter" ambas as vogais átonas eram seguidas por uma consoante muda, e ambas eram pronunciadas fechadas. Neste caso, o legislador eliminou ambas as consoantes mudas;
- em "collectivo" ambas as vogais átonas eram seguidas por uma consoante muda, sendo a primeira pronunciada fechada e a segunda pronunciada aberta. Neste caso, o legislador eliminou a consoante muda que seguia a átona fechada e manteve a consoante muda que seguia a átona aberta;
-em "facção" o /a/ átono era pronunciado aberto e o legislador manteve a consoante muda;
-em "satisfacção" o /a/ átono era pronunciado fechado, o legislador eliminou a consoante muda.
-em "illação", o /a/ átono era pronunciado aberto, e assim se manteve sem necessidade de "consoante muda diacrítica", o que, por si só, serviria (como serve) para demonstrar a aberração em análise.

Significa isto que a conjugação das bases 7, 8 e 9 da RO1911 não foi o resultado da constatação da existência de uma correlação entre pronúncia excecional de vogais e consoantes mudas. Bem pelo contrário, a conjugação das bases 7, 8 e 9 da RO1911 foi uma "engenharia" ortográfica de que resultou a criação artificiosa de uma correlação estatística entre consoantes mudas e o valor fonético de algumas vogais, correlação essa que nunca tinha existido na ortografia da Língua Portuguesa.

Apesar da evidência do erro, o preceito vingou, e a RO1911 estipulou que a palavra actuar manteria a grafia antiga, apesar do /a/ átono fechado, mas efficaz passaria a escrever-se eficaz apesar do /e/ átono aberto; por outro lado, especular ou dilação eram (e são) pronunciados com vogais pré tónicas abertas sem que os falantes necessitassem de dispor uma consoante muda ou acento que assinalasse a pronúncia correta, tal como hoje.

O AO1990 veio pôr fim às "consoantes mudas diacríticas", uma aberração ortográfica gerada em Portugal pela RO1911. É importante notar que a correção de 1990 vem na sequência de outras correções à diacrítica de 1911 que já tinham sido efetuadas em reformas ortográficas anteriores, tanto em Portugal como no Brasil.

Comment: Precisas de indicar a proveniência do texto, de preferência incluindo uma hiperligação.

Comment: A Origem da resposta:http://emportuguezgrande.blogspot.com/p/a-origem-das-consoantes-mudas.html